# web sockets json.loads

Tags: python, python-3.6

Когда я получаю эти данные с websocket с помощью web_socket.recv и пытаюсь перевести json с json.loads то, получается ошибка - "maJzso = json.loads(new_result["data"]) TypeError: string indices must be integers"". В чем может быть проблема?

```
web_socket.send("test")
result = web_socket.recv()
maJzson = json.loads(result["data"])
print(maJzson)
```

Пример получаемой строки ответа result -

```
{"type":"newitems_go","data":"{\"i_quality\":\"\\u041f\\u0440\\u044f\\u043c\\u043e \\u0441 \\u0437\\u0430\\u0432\\u043e\\u0434\\u0430\",\"i_name_color\":\"D2D2D2\",\"i_classid\":\"992122820\",\"i_instanceid\":\"519977179\",\"i_market_hash_name\":\"Dual Berettas | Moon in Libra (Factory New)\",\"i_market_name\":\"Dual Berettas | \\u041b\\u0443\\u043d\\u0430 \\u0432 \\u0437\\u043d\\u0430\\u043a\\u0435 \\u0412\\u0435\\u0441\\u043e\\u0432 (\\u041f\\u0440\\u044f\\u043c\\u043e \\u0441 \\u0437\\u0430\\u0432\\u043e\\u0434\\u0430)\",\"ui_price\":50.79,\"ui_currency\":\"RUB\",\"app\":\"go\"}"}
```

Comment: *>>Пример получаемой строки* - это не строка.

Comment: преобразование str(result) не помогает